# Can the default Gem install directory location be changed?

Tags: origen-sdk

I keep filling up my home directory with Origen-related gems!!   Is there an easy way to have Origen use a different directory by default so I don't go over my quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default Origen will configure Bundler (the tool used to fetch and manage Gems) for you, trying to take into account the fact that many users of Origen will be working in a corporate environment where Ruby may be installed to a central location that they don't have write access to.

If that doesn't apply to you, then you can take complete control of Bundler yourself. To do that, read up on how the [Origen site config system](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/company/) works, and set the `gem_manage_bundler` variable to false. One way of doing that is to set an environment variable called `ORIGEN_GEM_MANAGE_BUNDLER` to 0, and generally any site config variable can be set in this way by setting a corresponding env variable named `ORIGEN_<UPPERCASED VAR NAME>`.

Most users won't want to go that far and will simply want to move the default location of the gem install dir, if for example, there is a size limit placed on their home directory.
Typically, that would be done by setting the `ORIGEN_GEM_INSTALL_DIR` env variable to the required path.
Your workspace may need to be re-built for that to take effect, or running the [./bin/fix_my_workspace script](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/starting/workspace/#Fix_My_Workspace) should trigger a re-build within your workspace that will apply the new location.